# why the Code Does not work

Tags: php

in **"$grandtotal1"** and **"$grandtotal2"** does not display the sum

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
        $tgl        =$data['date_added'];
        $jenis_pemilik=$data['pemilik'];
        $no_invoice =$data['order_id'];
        $pengiriman =$data['shipping_method'];
        $berat      =$data['weight'];
        $namabarang =$data['name'];
        $artikel    =$data['model'];
        $retails    =$data['retail']*1;
        $odv        =$data['odv'];
        $ongkir     =$data['text'];
        $diskon     =$data['price']*1;
        $harga_jual =$data['harga_jual']*1;
        $stars      =(($harga_jual-$odv)*80)/100*1;
        $grandtotal1 +=($stars);
        $divisi     =(($harga_jual-$odv)*20)/100*1;
        $grandtotal2 +=($divisi);
```

I apply this code to FPDF does not work , but I apply to html page works

Comment: php uses the dot for concatenation,not the plus sign `.=`

Comment: Use tags correctly please.

Comment: still not working, i'm use $grandtotal1 .=($stars);

Comment: String concatenation actually works fine with `.=`. Why do you multiply by 1?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood something. If you want to add them you have to initialize `$grandtotal1` and `$grandtotal2`

Comment: ha ha @LPK - just posted that. Got in just before you - its a race!! :))

Comment: @gavgrif don't really mind ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from looking at your code - it seems you want to add 80% of an amount to $grandtotal1 and 20% to $grandtotal 2 - meaning that these are calculations and so the += is appropriate since you want to add numbers rather than concatenate values. I think the issue is that you haven't declared these values intiially so there is nothing to add them to.

before the while loop - declare the values:

```
$grandtotal1 = 0;      
$grandtotal2 = 0;
 while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){....
```

then when it is time, add the values

```
$stars      =(($harga_jual-$odv)*80)/100*1;
$grandtotal1 +=($stars);
$divisi     =(($harga_jual-$odv)*20)/100*1;
$grandtotal2 +=($divisi);
```

This will add the values of the calculations to each of the $grandTotals. not sure why you are multiplying all values by 1?